# PHP curl-setopt POST vs GET

Tags: php, php-curl

I am currently working with php-curls and I had a question on an example I was looking at, the code is below.

```
$url = "https://my.test.api";
$ch = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
             'Content-Type: application/json',
             'Content-Length: 0' ));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

The question I had is, on the line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");`, what would be a benefit here of using POST vs GET, if that is a thing. I understand the difference between the two just not the case of using it in this situation.

Coming from the PHP-manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

> A custom request method to use instead of "GET" or "HEAD" when doing a HTTP request. This is useful for doing "DELETE" or other, more obscure HTTP requests. Valid values are things like "GET", "POST", "CONNECT" and so on; i.e. Do not enter a whole HTTP request line here. For instance, entering "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" would be incorrect.

Which does not really make much sense to me.

Comment: That example you have doesnt actually send any POST or GET values, so thats odd.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I am creating a web based tool calling a rest api. I was given this as an example and trying to figure out why "POST" was used over "GET". The person who wrote this is now away on vacation so I can not ask for further explaination from him.

Comment: Well, if it sent data, then it would determine why and which way. But since it doesn't ... either way works, as it simply hits the server and expects a response.

Comment: Given that this was an "example", I imagine that in _practice_, you will be sending a raw JSON payload. That's why it's using POST.

Comment: @PatrickQ thats my guess too, due to the header being adjusted. The example is missing the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS bit it seems.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a REST api, a truly RESTful service will use HTTP semantics for what it is doing.  You GET data that already exists.  You POST new data. You PUT changes to data. You DELETE data.

Now, as far as actually working with an API, you can indeed use cURL for all 4 methods.  However, it is often much easier, simple, and less code to use `file_get_contents()` for GET requests, IF your PHP install allows HTTP(s) URIs for the various `fopen` and related functions.